# pyramid beaker cache issue - TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, pyramid, beaker

.ini file

```
cache.regions = default_term, second, short_term, long_term
cache.type = memcached
cache.url = 127.0.0.1:11211
cache.second.expire = 1
cache.short_term.expire = 60
cache.default_term.expire = 300
cache.long_term.expire = 3600
```

`__init__.py` file

```
from pyramid_beaker import set_cache_regions_from_settings
def main(global_config, **settings):
set_cache_regions_from_settings(settings)
...
```

test.py file

```
from beaker.cache import CacheManager
from beaker.util import parse_cache_config_options

cache_opts = {
'cache.data_dir': '/tmp/cache/data',
'cache.lock_dir': '/tmp/cache/lock',
'cache.regions': 'short_term, long_term',
'cache.short_term.type': 'ext:memcached',
'cache.short_term.url': '127.0.0.1.11211',
'cache.short_term.expire': '3600',
'cache.long_term.type': 'file',
'cache.long_term.expire': '86400',
}

cache = CacheManager(**parse_cache_config_options(cache_opts))

@cache.region('short_term', 'test')
def test_method(*args, **kwargs):
```

On executing the above code it gives error:

```
...
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\python_memcached-1.48-py2.7.egg\memcache.py", line      1058, in __init__
self.port = int(hostData.get('port', 11211))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Any idea what may be causing the error/ or I am missing anything ??

Comment: look at `hostData['port']`.  It seems like it is `None` ... ( I don't know why, and I suppose that I'm just assuming `hostData` is a dictonary ...)

Comment: You cut of a big part of your traceback; presumably it comes from your test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your test configuration, the `url` setting has an error in it:

```
'cache.short_term.url': '127.0.0.1.11211',
```

Note that there is no `:` colon in there. The memcached module you use, uses regular expressions to try and parse that value, and that method sets `port` to None when you specify that value as a host:

```
>>> host = '127.0.0.1.11211'
>>> re.match(r'^(?P<host>[^:]+)(:(?P<port>[0-9]+))?$', host).groupdict()
{'host': '127.0.0.1.11211', 'port': None}
```

which is the source of your traceback. Change the `cache_opts` dict to read:

```
'cache.short_term.url': '127.0.0.1:11211',
```

and things will work fine:

```
>>> host = '127.0.0.1:11211'
>>> re.match(r'^(?P<host>[^:]+)(:(?P<port>[0-9]+))?$', host).groupdict()
{'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': '11211'}
```